# How to build node.js app on raspberry pi with Ubuntu Snappy now?

Tags: nodejs, ubuntu-core, snap

I used to use node-snapper to build node.js app running in ubuntu snappy while in the recent updates, the tutorial page on ubuntu.com has been removed and only snapcraft is mentioned now.

From my understanding, even if I specify the architectures in snapcraft.yaml, snapcraft will still use my host machine (amd64) to compile binaries, which it cannot be used in raspberry pi (armhf).

Is there any other way to package node.js app into snappy?

Answer (score 1):

I guess this is related to [How to crossbuild apps for ubuntu core with snapcraft](https://askubuntu.com/questions/739685/how-to-crossbuild-apps-for-ubuntu-core-with-snapcraft).

Note that Snappy Ubuntu Core 16.04 (still in development) have a classic dimension which enables you to directly build on the device, so you won't have cross-arch issues anymore with this.